# how to generate a unique debitnote number automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

in my rails3 app i have a debitnote controller ,model and views created by scaffold.
i show you the migration:

```
class CreateDebitnotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :debitnotes do |t|
      t.string :debit_note_number
      t.date :date
      t.decimal :amount, :precision =>18, :scale => 2
      t.string :debit_account_of
      t.string :debit_for
      t.text :description

     t.timestamps
   end
 end
```

def self.down
    drop_table :debitnotes
  end
end

in my app i want to automatically generate a unique debitnote number when user open new form to create a deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use UUID generator [github repo](https://github.com/assaf/uuid)